# C sprintf implementation with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, format, printf, buffer

Im trying to Write a code that takes a buffer, a format string and three void pointers to values and composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf. the values being pointed at should replace the 3 placeholders in the format string. i started to code only for cases of `%c` placeholder and the buffer seems to contain random chars instead of the one being pointed at. any help will be appreciated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int format_to_string(char *buffer, char *format, void *arg1, void *arg2, void
*arg3);
int main(){
char format[20] = "%c bla %c bla %c";
int v1='5'; 
char v2 ='c';
char v3 = 'F';
void *arg1 = &v1;
void *arg2 = &v2;
void *arg3 = &v3;
char str[20];
char *buffer = str;
format_to_string(buffer,format, &arg1, &arg2,&arg3);
printf("%s",buffer);
return 0;

}
int format_to_string(char *buffer, char *format, void *arg1, void *arg2, void
*arg3)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; *format != '\0'; format++, buffer++ )
    {
        if( *format != '%')
        {
            *buffer = *format;
        }
        else
        {
            format++;
            if(*format == 'c')
            {
                if(counter == 0)
                {
                    *buffer =*(char*)arg1;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
                if(counter == 1)
                {
                    *buffer =*(char*)arg2;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
                if(counter == 2)
                {
                    *buffer =*(char*)arg3;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
            }    
        }

    }   
    *buffer = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: corner case bug: Note that if the format was an unexpected "abc %", code would increment `format` past the `'\0'`;  Suggest `if(*format == 'c') { .... } else { *buffer = '\0';
    return 0; }` to exit parsing early rather than go too far.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking your indirection a bit too far. You have:

```
format_to_string(buffer,format, &arg1, &arg2,&arg3);
```

But `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` are already pointers. So you're taking the addresses of the addresses your values, and what you're printing is the addresses of the values instead of the values themselves. Instead, just pass the args:

```
format_to_string(buffer,format, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 0):

For each of the extra arguments to `format_to_string` you are sending them as a pointer to pointer to char (two levels of indirection) while the function is expecting pointer to char (one level of indirection). You can fix this either of the following ways:

1) Change argument types in your call to `format_to_string`, so that you are only passing the pointer to the previously defined chars. (This makes the most sense based on your current code).

```c
    void *arg1 = &v1;
    void *arg2 = &v2;
    void *arg3 = &v3;
    //...
    format_to_string(buffer,format, arg1, arg2,arg3);
```

2) Change the parameter types of `format_to_string`

```c
    int format_to_string(char *buffer, char *format, void **arg1, void **arg2, void **arg3)
    {
    //...
                if(counter == 0)
                {
                    *buffer =**(char*)arg1;
                    counter++;
                    continue;
                }
    //...
    }
```

P.S. If you are interested accepting more than three arguments (like printf) you can use [variable argument lists](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html)